# Update bindings when element is updated outside angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, daterangepicker

I have a date picker as follows:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="dob" class="col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
    <input type="text" name="daterangepicker" id="dob" class="form-control form-control-sm"
           ng-model="dtDateOfBirth" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ng-click="age()">Age</button>
</div>
```

... and I am using the [daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com) library. I need to allow the date to be empty even when the user has clicked the `input` and navigated away. So I used the `autoUpdateInput = false` in the settings as shown below

```
$('input[name="daterangepicker"]').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoUpdateInput: false,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        cancelLabel: 'Clear'
    }
});

$('input[name="daterangepicker"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD-MMM-YYYY'));
});

$('input[name="daterangepicker"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

But the issue is, the `$scope.dtDateOfBirth` is not updated when the user selects a date. How do I tell `angularjs` that the variable needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). because the Model is not updated for the jquery callback.

```js
app.directive("daterangepicker", function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      elem.daterangepicker({
          singleDatePicker: true,
          showDropdowns: true,
          autoUpdateInput: false,
          locale: {
              format: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
              cancelLabel: 'Clear'
          }
      });
      elem.on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.daterangepicker);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
        scope.$apply(function () {
          modelSetter(scope, { startDate: picker.startDate.toDate(), endDate: picker.endDate.toDate() });
        });

      });
    }
  }

});
```

```html
div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="dob" class="col-form-label">Date of Birth:</label>
    <input type="text" name="daterangepicker" id="dob" class="form-control form-control-sm"                           daterangepicker="dtDateOfBirth"
           ng-model="dtDateOfBirth" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ng-click="age()">Age</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am getting `modelSetter is not a function` when I select a date. It's failing on the `modelSetter()` function in the `$scope.$apply()` part